# Where in the Andean Road System was this picture taken? What are the white formations?

Tags: south-america

I saw this picture:

[image]

on here: https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1459/gallery/

Does anyone know where this was taken? What are the white formations on the right?

Comment: Wow! Snow [Hoodoos](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoodoo)!

Comment: The lock photo on Windows for me a few days ago was such a formation from Japan.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The white formations are snow & ice formations called [penitentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penitente_(snow_formation)):

> Penitentes... are snow formations found at high altitudes. They take the form of elongated, thin blades of hardened snow or ice, closely spaced and pointing towards the general direction of the sun. ... These spires of snow and ice grow over all glaciated and snow-covered areas in the Dry Andes above 4,000 metres (13,000 ft).

The precise location of this photo is not clear but it is possible to find many pictures of such formations in other locations as well.  There are a couple of theories as to how they get their strange shape;  [this article](https://www.ststworld.com/penitentes-ice-pillars/) summarizes a few of them.

I found this information by doing a [Google Image search](https://lens.google.com/search?ep=gisbubb&hl=en&re=df&p=ATHekxcOBvQzdLyfTzZTtTyV7wMuMIq-DOMMGS3YtSR9gA4nBlDgX0xIfcke5v1JNLHP1_07AbIN-mbZMEFTcvvFhIhs-q1cRHKdfb35nWuHj-uDGvr59t3w-z4pfQNcDcQrnHFc8M8b7CYzadf5LHc_LVIaYx5EmiwJyg_fA7ZvVgsTgP7SZOjbxcYGBJVV4T2jSQTMfFe0tWB82FtZn14iWpcXsq4%3D#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKR1JqT1dNd1ltSTJMV0UzT1RFdE5EY3haaTFpTm1JNExXTTVPRFkzTkRBMVpHUTFZeElmWnpOblNIQnFNemh4WVRobWMwRmhRM1F0VldoaFp6WmxURXhJYW1wNFp3PT0iLG51bGwsbnVsbCxbW251bGwsbnVsbCwiMS0wIl0sWyI1MGYzNzk3Yy0xYjc2LTRkMTUtYjRhNS1mYTU1YTFiYjM5MzciXV1d) on the image you posted.  While this did not yield more information on this particular picture, I found several like it which led me to the correct search term.

Comment: Even here in Minnesota, in some winters (depending on snowfall, temperatures, sunniness), similar structures form. They are usually short-lived.

Comment: @paulgarrett And smaller. I call them shark teeth.

Answer (score 22):

Michael Seifert [has covered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/182030/) what the formations in the photo are. The location is near the summit of the Llullaillaco Volcano on the border of Chile and Argentina.

Compare the photo in the question with the following photo of the volcano from a similar angle below. This shows the peak with a very similar profile and with snow fields in similar positions. A field of penitentes can also be seen in the foreground.

[image]
<sub>Published [here](https://universes.art/en/art-destinations/qhapaq-nan), photo copyright Mario Lazarovich</sub>

Comment: Diego Sberna, the person credited with the photo, also went on an expedition to this volcano around the time the photo was reportedly taken: http://qhapaqnan-salta-argentina.blogspot.com/2010/11/expedicion-al-volcan-llullaillaco.html